# Will Python print() broke CMD in long term?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

If I made python 3.x program that run on windows cmd and print some log.
Will it consume all memory in RAN in long term? or CMD will delete old log by its self?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMD will remove the old log/output. So nothing will be broken.